# Wrong custom formatted price in Woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, price

I'm trying to show my WooCommerce price formatted and it works. 
Currently, my site shows the value of the product and soon after, it shows the value of it divided by 10.

But when the price exceeds the value of 1000, the formatting instead of showing `1000/10 = 100`, is showing `0.10`. What I'm doing wrong?

```
$preco_12 = $price / 10;
$preco_formatado = number_format($preco_12, 2, '.', '');
$return          = '<p class="preco-interno">Ou em até 10x sem juros de <span class="cifrao">R$' .$preco_formatado . '</span> </p>
```

Comment: might be because `1.000/10` = `0.10` your calculations might see it as 1,0 instead of 1000

Comment: basically, remove any formating syntax before your math - if you never have decibels, you can just str_replace

Comment: You were right. I just removed WooCommerce default formmating and it worked. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was using WooCommerce default formmating and formatting it again by myself, 2 times.

I just had to use $unformatted_price from WooCommerce and use my $preco_formatado to format it again.